# How to validate session in CodeIgniter from database?

Tags: codeigniter

I want to secure my session and hence I am storing the session in ci_sessions table in database. But I want to know how to check the session id matches every time the user logged IN?. I don't know how ci_sessions table actually works. Can anyone suggest me?

```
my config.php file
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Check if *`id`* exists in session:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('id') === NULL)
{
    // User is not logged in, redirect to login screen
}
else
{
    // User is logged in, allow access
}
```